# "say" or "tell" in this context

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english

> **Teacher:** Who can **say** the multiplication table from 1 to 10.

Or,

> **Teacher:** Who can **tell** me the multiplication table from 1 to 10.

Which of the two sentences is more appropriate for a teacher to use in a classroom?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

If you're trying to find the difference between *tell* and *say* by using this example, see: 
[What is the difference between “say” and “tell”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67738/what-is-the-difference-between-say-and-tell).

However, if you really are specifically interested in this scenario, then  of the two choices, <strike>*say* is better</strike> *tell me*<sup>*</sup> is better:

> Teacher: Who can **tell me** the multiplication table from 1 to 10.

<sup>*I misread the original as *say the* and *tell **the***.</sup>
As the linked post suggests, the basic patterns are *say something* and *tell someone*. Both choices are grammatically correct, but idiomatically, we don’t *say the multiplication* table.

Since children are taught to memorize the times tables and then repeat them from memory, a good alternative is *recite*:

> Teacher: Who can **recite** the multiplication table from 1 to 10?

(Also, question mark.)

Here are a couple of relevant dictionary entries:

> - [Definition of recite](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recite)
>     transitive verb
>     1 : to repeat from memory or read aloud publicly
>
> (M-W)
>
> - [recite](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/recite)
>     verb (used with object), re·cit·ed, re·cit·ing.
>     to repeat the words of, as from memory, especially in a formal manner:
>     *to recite a lesson.*
>
> (Dictionary.com)

Comment: Yep - recite is the word I would pick (BrE speaker)

Comment: I'd go further to emphasise that in the given phrases that neither of the proferred choices are likely: 'recite' is the most likely.

Comment: Furthermore, none of these are likely to be *said*. : 'Who *knows* their multiplication table*s* from 1~10' (everyone raises their hand). *Their* tables; it's never 'the'.

Comment: @Mazura  I disagree - these tables belong to everyone, not to a particular person, so I would regard 'the' as more normal usage than 'their'.

Comment: Speaking from American English experience, "Who can tell me..." or "Can anyone tell me..." are common, almost idiomatic, ways to ask a group of people a question. "Who can say..." does not seem natural for this scenario.

Comment: @HarrisonPaine Thanks for the comment. I realized I misread the original as _say the_ and _tell **the**_, in which case I thought _say the_ was the lesser of the two evils, so to speak.

Comment: @MikeBrockington - *the* multiplication table belongs to everyone. *My* multiplication tables from 6~8 are kinda fuzzy. This is a teacher, not a tutor (more than one student), so it's *theirs* not *your*. And it's a possessive pronoun(?) not a definite article, because we need to know which ones *you're* fuzzy on.

Answer (score -1):

I think the second is most appropriate to be said to students by a teacher. 'Tell' means 'Who can prove their knowledge of multiplication to me'. 'Say' or 'recite' just means 'Who can mindlessly parrot multiplication tables into space'.

Comment: I agree with the second part of this answer regarding recitation, but not the first. In BrE there is no significant distinction between "tell" and "say" in this sort of context. One might say "tell me how to.." or  "say what you did during the holidays" - same basic syntax, same basic meaning.

Comment: Not the same, because one asks for a direct communication, the other is requesting a broadcast.

Comment: In some cases, that is true, but it is not accurate in the example that I gave, nor does it detract from my overall argument - "Tell" on its own does NOT mean "prove".

Comment: The first is definitely more appropriate: multiplication tables are _meant_ to be learnt by heart, and mindlessly parroted into space.