# Is it natural to say "You hate doing as I tell you"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

I think I often hear this structure in commands or requests "**do as I say / ask...**" or "**do as I tell you**"

So, "**to do as I tell you**" is a verb.

I am not sure if I put that verb into a sentence, will it sound natural anymore.

For example, "*He did as I told you*" or "*You hate doing as I tell you*".

I don't think "*He did as I told you*" or "*You hate doing as I tell you*" are grammatically wrong because I just put the correct verb "**to do as I tell you**" in a sentence, I didn't change the verb.

But, It seems some people said they are not natural. They said it's  better to say "*He did what I told him to do*" and "*You hate doing what I tell you to do*".

My question is
Why can we say "**do as I tell you**" but can not "*He did as I told you*" or "*You hate doing as I tell you*"?

English is very hard. A phrase, which can be used in a command, might sound awkward in a sentence.

Also, why "**Do as I tell you**" is correct but "**You hate doing as I tell you**" is not correct?

See these sentences:

1-"*cook dinner*"

2-"*you hate cooking dinner*" / "*You don't seem to like cooking dinner*"

3-"*Do as I tell you*"

4-"*You hate doing as I tell you*" / "*You don't seem to like doing as I tell you*"

I just put "**you hate**" or "**You don't seem to like**" in front of the verb. That's all.

But why the number 2 "*you hate cooking dinner*" / "*You don't seem to like cooking dinner*" sounds ok but the number 4 "*You hate doing as I tell you*" / "*You don't seem to like doing as I tell you*" doesn't?

**That is the main part of this question.**

Comment: The title should read: "You hate doing **what** I tell you [to do].“ the part in square brackets can be left out. It is different construct from "do as I say/tell"

Comment: Where did you hear or read that you can say 'do as I tell'?

Comment: It's **Do as I tell you**.  In this sense (as in to speak words, to say something), **tell** is a transitive verb and requires an object. For example: You tell me, I tell you, he tells someone, I tell him, etc.

Comment: @BillyKerr You. And you can say **Do as you're told!**. I heard that a lot as kid.

Comment: @tom There's a related question here, if not a duplicate: [What is the difference between “say” and “tell”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67738/what-is-the-difference-between-say-and-tell)

Comment: do as I say, do as I ask BUT do as I tell you [to do]

Comment: @BillyKerr, I understood the difference between "say" and "tell" ok, I just got mixed up. That is worth to talk about. Try to focus on the main part of the question

Comment: @tom I **am** focussing on your question. **Say** is often intranstive (e.g. Do as I say) and requires no object, but in this sense **tell** is transitive, and requires an object.  This is part of the difference between say and tell.

Comment: The word "hate" is an intense word.  You should use it cautiously.  In particular I would recommend *never* using "hate" about a person.  And never saying what someone else hates, unless you are reporting what they say.  So, I'd be cautious about "You hate...".  Are you really sure that their feeling are *that* strong?

Comment: @JamesK - yes, that's another issue.  Better to say "You don't seem to like doing  . . . "

Comment: @BillyKerr, try not to dig into my mistake of "say" and "tell". I got a mixed up, that's all. That is not worth to talk about. Instead, try to focus on the key part of the question: why "Do as I tell you" is correct but "You hate doing as I tell you" is not correct. That is all this question about

Comment: @tom with respect - you asked the question, and now you don't seem to like the answer. If you don't want honest answers, then that's not my problem. It's yours. And note: I have already told you why. I am done with this now, so there's no need to post any more comments directed towards me.

Comment: "Do as I do" which is imperative,  is the same as telling someone "Do the thing(s) that I am saying, but don't copy my actions" it is a different meaning from "Do what I tell you“ which means I expect you to obey my requests/instructions/commands. Imagine a boss talking to their worker.

Comment: “He did as I told you” would be unusual but perfectly fine: say I explained to you how to fix the brakes of a car but you didn’t listen, however, your colleague listened and followed the instructions I gave you.

Comment: The verbs like, dislike, hate, adore (and you can look up the full list) can take gerunds. So: like (declarative or negative)  + doing as I tell you is fine.  [by the way: Why **does** x sound (whatver)] Anyway, please stop changing your questions every time you ask one.

Comment: And the reason "people" say that: "He did what I told him to do" is better is because not many would *switch people* like this: "He did as I told **you**". A third party did what I told you to do. It's not the grammar at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are both idiomatic:

> You hate doing as I tell you.
>
> You hate doing what I tell you.

There is very little practical difference in meaning. The word  **as** refers to manner, *how* you want them to act or behave. The word **what** refers to the substance of your instruction, the "things" you tell them to do. But the same instruction could be perceived in either way, as act or action.

If you want to use the word **tell** to mean "instruct or command" you need an object:

> Do as I tell *you*.
>
> Do as I tell <sup>ungrammatical</sup>.
>
> Do as I say you <sup>ungrammatical</sup>
>
> Do as I say.

Comment: "You hate doing as I tell you" doesn't sound idiomatic to me (in the UK).

Comment: @StuartF Interesting. How, exactly?   "Hate doing"?  or "doing as I tell you"?

Comment: Here's a Brit from the early 20th century who "**hates doing** things by halves".  https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Osbornes/e5VKAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=He+hates+doing+as+I+tell+him&pg=PA227&printsec=frontcover

Comment: If both are idiomatic why are there exactly **two matches** on Google for [**"doing as I tell"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hate+doing+as+I+tell%22&sca_esv=b6ab7d9e5410acba&sxsrf=ACQVn09a5nUwstNAEc2QRH5LazuAkICJsA%3A1708959277625&ei=LabcZbjsJcWJ9u8P8-25-A0&ved=0ahUKEwj4tra1ocmEAxXFhP0HHfN2Dt8Q4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22hate+doing+as+I+tell%22&gs_sclient=gws-wiz-serp) and **one** match for [**"doing as he tells”**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hate+doing+as+he+tells%22&sca_esv=b6ab7d9e5410acba&sxsrf=t=gws-wiz-serp)

Answer (score 2):

`So, "to do as I tell" is a verb.` it is not a verb, it is a phrase. The main verb is "do" but instead of "to do" it should be in the imperative voice "Do"

**Do as I say** is a fixed phrase today, closer to an idiom, although dictionaries classify it as a proverb. The full quote, which is still current, is derived from the 1654 [*Table-Talk*](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Table_Talk_being_the_Discourses_of_John/s7hcAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22preachers%20say,%20do%20as%20I%20say%20not%20as%20I%20do%22&pg=PA118&printsec=frontcover) by John Selden:

> Preachers say, "Do as I say, not as I do”

**Do as I tell you [to]** (we must have a direct object after *tell*) appears to be a variation but its meaning is slightly different from the previous one. The speaker expects obedience from the listener, they are not acknowledging the hypocrisy as the 1654 quote admits.

> “You can have the dam gun but I want to keep my belt. [sic] I told him to unbuckle the belt and drop them on the ground. I would take the gun and hand his belt back to him. He did as I told him.
> Source: *[The Autobiography of Rufe LeFors](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Facts_as_I_Remember_Them/ct8jDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22you%20can%20have%20the%20dam%20gun%22%20%22he%20did%20as%20I%20told%22&pg=PA73&printsec=frontcover)*

**He did as I told him [to]** is grammatical but I think the more common phrase structure is

"[**he did as he was told**](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=a19c4e940f5aec6f&sxsrf=ACQVn0_IUtr-y1Eu3QtrqxzzOezCsbhlpg:1708866757314&q=%22did%20as%20he%20was%20told%22&tbm=bks&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiR0qbgyMaEAxWuSvEDHSinCy8Q0pQJegQIYRAB&biw=1152&bih=630&dpr=2.5)"

> So Joseph as obedient as before **did as he was told**. But when he reached the land he found that one of Herods' sons was ruling over the country where Bethlehem was. He was afraid to go there as he had meant to do, so he went to Nazareth where Mary's early home used to be.
> Source: *Sunday School Helper* (1894)

To answer the OP's question

> “Is it natural to say "You hate doing as I tell"?”

**No,** as well as not sounding natural, it is also ungrammatical. The correct form would be

> “**You hate doing what I tell you [to do]**”

the part in square brackets can be omitted.  The sentence means that the listener strongly dislikes being told how to behave and/or ignores the speaker's instructions.

Comment: But you didn't say the difference between  "You hate doing as I tell you" and “You hate doing what I tell you"?

Comment: The first is ungrammatical, the second means the listener hates being told what to do.

Comment: You had better updated your answer because I updated my question.

Comment: But you didn't say why "Do as I tell you" is correct but "You hate doing as I tell you" is not correct?

Comment: Alos, try not to dig into my mistake of "say" and "tell". I got a mixed up, that's all. That is not worth talking about. Instead, try to focus on the key part of the question: why "Do as I tell you" is correct but "You hate doing as I tell you" is not correct

Comment: The mistake was there though, repeatedly, and it's not unusual for non-native speakers to leave out the object after "tell". It's a common error in writing. My first comment included "tell" with the pronoun but it's only when I posted the answer that you realised the question title and the example were ungrammatical. Look at when people said it was not natural–you even quoted their answers, and they all included the object pronoun. So... from my experience and what you wrote I wasn't digging into anything. I was blunt and truthful when I said  "You hate doing as I tell" is ungrammatical.

Comment: You tried hard not to answer my question. Also, I updated my question already. But you can not answer why "Do as I tell you" sound ok but "You hate doing as I tell you" does not. But why both "cook dinner" and "you hate cooking dinner" are ok. You just don't know do you?

Comment: Your now-deleted comment asked **what was the difference in meaning** between "Do as I say" and "I hate doing as you tell” . I edited and explained the difference in meaning. You deleted the comment. Now you have changed the question, which I saw exactly 10 minutes ago. NOW you want to say why you can't say "You hate doing as I tell you" That's a different question. I spent time composing an answer to an older question, I did the research, I looked for references and supporting evidence. Now, you're asking me to scrap all of that out and start afresh?

Comment: There is no difference inasmuch as   "**you hate doing**" follows the same pattern as the one cited by you, e.g. **You hate cooking**. The difference is in the usage of "as I tell you", you need instead the pronoun **what**  if it's to be grammatical. **You hate doing what (the things)  I tell you to do**

Comment: This is from a chatbot: "I did as you told me" implies that you followed the instructions or guidance given by the person you are addressing. It suggests that you followed their specific directions or requests without deviation. The emphasis here is on the act of following the instructions exactly as they were given.

Comment: And this is also from a chatbot: On the other hand, "I did what you told me" suggests that you carried out the general or overall task or command given by the person. It implies that you completed the task or followed the command, but it doesn't necessarily imply that you followed the instructions in a strict or precise manner. The emphasis here is on the completion of the task rather than the exact details of how it was done.